# Visio 2016 has stopped displaying words and text

Tags: microsoft-visio

All of a sudden Visio 2016 stopped displaying words and text. It only shows graphical elements. I see popup dialogs but cannot read them because there are no words. [Click here to see what this looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iw7Q.png)

I tried to repair it from Control Panel with the "Quick Repair" option, nothing changed.

I tried to repair it from Control Panel with the "Online Repair" option. That deleted Visio and all my other Office 2016 Professional Plus applications.

I reinstalled Office 2016, and Word, Excel, PowerPoint, and Outlook appear to be working.

But when I re-installed Visio 2016, it still doesn't display any words or text.

I suppose something must have changed in my system to cause this, but I don't know what, and I don't know where to find a record of it.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: cross-posts which contain screenshot  [Visio 2016 is corrupt, it displays no words or text](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8cf4ed34-0079-4ddb-aa60-56944c210c3d/visio-2016-is-corrupt-it-displays-no-words-or-text?forum=visiogeneral), [Visio 2016 has stopped displaying words and text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45807077/visio-2016-has-stopped-displaying-words-and-text)

Comment: I would initially check your video drivers are up to date.

Comment: If the video drivers fix appears to be the answer then I shall rewrite my comment as such.

Answer (score 0):

I would check that your video drivers are up to date